# Cropping video on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video

I'm currently making an iPhone app for my department, and we have a video we'd like to incorporate in to it. The video has a frame around it in which we'd like to crop out. Is there anyway you can do this directly with code? Or do I need to actually go and edit the video using some other tools? I've attached a screen shot of the video. I essentially want to crop out the tan areas around the actual video.

[image: example of video]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this is entirely possible in Xcode, however it involves use of CoreVideo which, at least in my experience, isn't the easier framework to use. However to save time and effort you can crop your clip in iMovie like so...

Also, this method will decrease your application's bundle size.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just had another thought, cropping the video externally will also help you keep down your total app file size.

Comment: Good point MDT, but the video is being pulled off a server, so size isn't a huge issue right now. I'm going to look into CoreVideo, but if it is too much of a calorie burner, I'll just use your method. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, good luck!
this might be a good place to start
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010036